# Error: Could not find Chrome (ver. 119.0.6045.105). This can occur if either

Tags: php, laravel, google-chrome, puppeteer, browsershot

I'm using this Laravel package: https://github.com/spatie/browsershot to take a screenshot. It's based on Puppeteer

But when I run it returns this error

Error Output:

```
Error: Could not find Chrome (ver. 119.0.6045.105). This can occur if either
 1. you did not perform an installation before running the script (e.g. `npx puppeteer browsers install chrome`) or
 2. your cache path is incorrectly configured (which is: /home/sail/.cache/puppeteer).
For (2), check out our guide on configuring puppeteer at https://pptr.dev/guides/configuration.
    at ChromeLauncher.resolveExecutablePath (/var/www/html/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/ProductLauncher.js:278:27)
    at ChromeLauncher.executablePath (/var/www/html/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/ChromeLauncher.js:209:25)
    at ChromeLauncher.computeLaunchArguments (/var/www/html/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/ChromeLauncher.js:103:37)
    at async ChromeLauncher.launch (/var/www/html/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/ProductLauncher.js:69:28)
    at async callChrome (/var/www/html/vendor/spatie/browsershot/bin/browser.cjs:91:23)
 {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Process\\Exception\\ProcessFailedException(code: 0): The command \"PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin NODE_PATH=`npm root -g` node '/var/www/html/vendor/spatie/browsershot/src/../bin/browser.cjs' '{\"url\":\"file:\\/\\/\\/tmp\\/2013666216-0476504001704712330\\/index.html\",\"action\":\"screenshot\",\"options\":{\"type\":\"jpeg\",\"quality\":100,\"args\":[\"--no-sandbox\"],\"viewport\":{\"width\":1200,\"height\":630},\"displayHeaderFooter\":false,\"newHeadless\":true}}'\" failed.
```

I checked the `/home/sail/.cache/puppeteer/chrome` and see there is an folder name `linux-115.0.5790.170/chrome-linux64` so I think Chrome already downloaded success.

Do you know why?

Comment: Not the same versions though. Would https://spatie.be/docs/browsershot/v4/requirements#content-custom-chromechromium-executable-path help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, after 12 hours of debugging and feeling crazy, I finally made it work

Since Puppeteer v19, the Chrome will be saved to `~/.cache/puppeteer` instead of inside `node_modules`

But some servers don't allow to read the `~/.cache/puppeteer`, that's why it's there but still shows the `Could not find` error. You need to move the `.cache` folder to your root project.

In my case, I create a `.puppeteerrc.cjs` file

```
const {join} = require('path');

/**
 * @type {import("puppeteer").Configuration}
 */
module.exports = {
    // Changes the cache location for Puppeteer.
    cacheDirectory: join(__dirname, '.cache', 'puppeteer'),
};
```

Make sure you uninstall and re-install the Puppeteer again:

```
npm remove puppeteer
npm install puppeteer
```

After that, we need to install some required dependencies here https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/troubleshooting.md#chrome-doesnt-launch-on-linux

I'm using Ubuntu so I need to install:

```
ca-certificates
fonts-liberation
libasound2
libatk-bridge2.0-0
libatk1.0-0
libc6
libcairo2
libcups2
libdbus-1-3
libexpat1
libfontconfig1
libgbm1
libgcc1
libglib2.0-0
libgtk-3-0
libnspr4
libnss3
libpango-1.0-0
libpangocairo-1.0-0
libstdc++6
libx11-6
libx11-xcb1
libxcb1
libxcomposite1
libxcursor1
libxdamage1
libxext6
libxfixes3
libxi6
libxrandr2
libxrender1
libxss1
libxtst6
lsb-release
wget
xdg-utils
```

Answer (score 1):

Locate your .cache folder at `/home/sail/.cache/puppeteer` , as stated in the error and move it to your root directory.
Then, remove puppeteer

```
npm remove puppeteer
```

and install it again

```
npm install puppeteer
```

This should solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue a while back for an automated test using Selenium that was using a headless browser to login to a remote site and retrieve a file. Whenever Chrome updated, the version didn't match.

Try using :

```
sudo apt install google-chrome-stable
```

to update your installed Chrome to the latest binaries and then re-run.

Comment: Note that linux distributions that do not have aptitude as their package manager will have a different way of installing chrome. Also this method requires you to add the chrome repositories to aptitude.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it the following way:

- Remove node_modules folder
- In package.json file, update the puppeteer version to the latest (just google for latest version)
- After that, do npm install

now it will work like a charm!!!!!