Error: Could not find Chrome / your cache path is incorrectly configured
I have a NodeJS script which uses puppeteer. This script is launched by Laravel (a PHP framework).
Everything works fine in local, because laravel is run under my current user account, which means the script ran also with this account.
But on my server, Laravel runs with an Apache account (www-data) so the JS script too.
When the script use puppeteer I got :
Error: Could not find Chrome (ver. 130.0.6723.58). This can occur if either
 1. you did not perform an installation before running the script (e.g. `npx puppeteer browsers install chrome`) or
 2. your cache path is incorrectly configured (which is: /var/www/.cache/puppeteer).
For (2), check out our guide on configuring puppeteer at https://pptr.dev/guides/configuration.
    at ChromeLauncher.resolveExecutablePath (file:///home/admin/node-twitterbot/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/esm/puppeteer/node/BrowserLauncher.js:266:27)
    at ChromeLauncher.executablePath (file:///home/admin/node-twitterbot/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/esm/puppeteer/node/ChromeLauncher.js:202:25)
    at ChromeLauncher.computeLaunchArguments (file:///home/admin/node-twitterbot/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/esm/puppeteer/node/ChromeLauncher.js:83:37)

So I did :
sudo -u www-data npx puppeteer browsers install chrome chromium -- path=/var/www/.cache/puppeteer

And in the .cache folder, chrome and chromium are there.
But I still got the exception.
Any ideas?
Thanks

Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77779601/error-could-not-find-chrome-ver-119-0-6045-105-this-can-occur-if-either

This question is similar to: Error: Could not find Chrome (ver. 119.0.6045.105). This can occur if either. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I had to specify the location of the browser :
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
executablePath: '/usr/bin/chromium'
})
